# How to interpret pairwise interaction matrix?

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model

I've created a pairwise interaction matrix for my glm but I'm not sure how to use the matrix to interpret and improve my model based on the results.

```
 all_model <- glm(y ~. , data = train_df, family = "binomial")  

 interactions <- model.matrix(y ~ .^, data = train_df)
```

and it looks like this

```
 intercept      gender     age    income_range
    1              0        0           1
    1              0        0           0
    1              0        1           0
```

etc..

I'm not sure where to go beyond here and the only answers I've see just show how to get the matrix but not how to interpret and use it to improve the model. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The model matrix just tells you what predictor variables are included in your model and in what form (in addition to the intercept).  From what you posted, it seems like you are fitting a model of the form:

```
all_model <-  glm(y ~ gender + age + income_range,
                 family = "binomial", 
                 data = train_df)
```

If y is a binary variable such that 1 = "success" and 0 = "failure", then your model is a binary logistic regression model which allows you to relate the log odds of success linearly to gender, age and income_range. Another way to think about this model is that it allows you to model the probability of success as a (nonlinear) function of gender, age and income_range.

Note that the model matrix is not an interaction matrix - at least not for your current model, which includes only main effects for your predictor variables but no interactions.

If you want your model to include two-way interactions between all pairs of predictors and a three-way interaction between all three predictors, you would specify it like this:

```
all_model_three_way <-  glm(y ~ gender * age * income_range,
                       family = "binomial", 
                       data = train_df)
```

If you want your model to include only two-way interactions between all pairs of predictors, you would specify it like this:

```
all_model_two_way <-  glm(y ~ I(gender+age+income_range)^2,
                     family = "binomial", 
                     data = train_df)
```

Usually we don't interpret the model matrix - we might extract it just to verify the model was correctly specified or to use it in some other calculations.